# ReactJS: Props not available immediately?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that needs to access a prop when it gets mounted. Actually, I am using a prop to define proper state in getInitialState(), but as it may be an anti-pattern, I also tried accessing it in componentWillMount/componentDidMount, but it is always empty at this point of the lifecycle.

Here's a shortened example:

```
// MyComponent
module.exports = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        projectId:  React.PropTypes.number,
        customerId: React.PropTypes.number
    },

    getDefaultProps() {
        return {
            projectId:  null,
            customerId: null
        }
    },

    componentWillMount() {
        this.getNamespace()
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getNamespace()
    },

    getNamespace() {
        var str = "items"

        if (this.props.customerId) str += "_c" + this.props.customerId
        if (this.props.projectId)  str += "_p" + this.props.projectId

        // this.props.projectId is always empty here
        // this.props.customerId is always empty here
        // so str is always "items"

        console.log("NS is " + str)
        console.log(this.props)

        return str
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <AppModule />
        )
    }
})

// Usage:
<MyComponent customerId="1" projectId="2" />
```

Why is this.props.projectId and this.props.customerId always empty in getInitialState, componentWillMount and componentDidMount? What am I doing wrong and how should I solve it? Don't want to just use a dirty setTimeout and wait :)

Oh, before I forget: I actually CAN use these props. But not at this state. Also, the component that is calling my component does not refresh the props or anything like that. At least I think so.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It looks like you have a mix of ES6 ('componentWillMount()' instead of 'componentWillMount: function()' in combination with 'React.createClass'). I've never seen this before, so I'm unsure whether this might cause a problem. Further more, if you really want to pass numeric values in JSX attributes, you should use 'customerId={1}' instead of 'customerId="1"'.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, I expected props to be immediately available but they seem not to be likely because they come from a parent which relies on a (relatively) long running external call to build those props.
Using componentDidMount did not work for me but componentWillReceiveProps did work nicely. I would think you could call getNamespace from there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :)

```
  if (this.props.customerId) str += "_c" + this.props.customerId
```

Also I think you won't access props in componentWillMount.

But I'm wondering, where do you define props values ? =/

Comment: Sorry, you're right :) But it does not really solve the problem, as it gets the same result. console.log(this.props) returns Object {customerId: null, projectId: null}. :(

Comment: that's why I'm asking where do you define props values ? how do you instanciate your component ?